# Issue in Using Truecrypt

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I have encrypted my external HDD using true crypt and the functionalities of Truecrypt seems to be working fine.

I have configured a traveler's disk setup so as to run truecrypt from within the HDD even if the destination PC does not have Truecrypt installed.

I'm able to mount the encrpted volume and unmount the same without any issues but when I want to eject my HDD it says `Windows can't stop your 'Generic volume' device because a aprogram is still using it.Close any programs that might be using the device, and then try again later.`

Then I have to shutdown/re-start my pc to remove the HDD.

But on a new system re-start if I don't mount the encrpted volume then I'm ble to eject many times without any issues.

So I think once mounting the volume I cannot remove my HDD but if I don't mount at all I'm not facing any issues.

I checked to see if Truecrpt is still running in background and checked in "System Tray" and "Task Manager" but it does not seem to be running.

So how can I remove my external HDD if I choose to use Truecrypt, BTW I have Win 7  OS.

Comment: I didn't use the "traveler" mode, but I thinkn you have to open TrueCrypt and press unmount...

Comment: Do you have a window like this: http://www.chip.de/ii/8/4/1/2/2/9/e73dd811e9c31ed4.jpg ?

Comment: @davidbaumann : Even in the "Traveller" mode the "Dismount" option is available and when I click it the encrypted volume gets dismounted fine, the only issue is I'm not able to eject the HDD once I decide to use Truecrypt.

Comment: @davidbaumann : Yes, I do have the window as you mentioned and I have all options too.

Comment: So just select the tc virtual device and unmount.

Comment: As I previously mentioned, I did and the encrypted volume gets un-mounted too, but I'm not able to eject my external HDD and it gives me the error I've mentioned above.